# R- Finding cumulative values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have COVID data. It gives the number of cases and deaths of European countries on certain dates. I need to select 10 countries and show the cases after the 1000th confirmed case by drawing a line. Countries are listed under a column titled countries, number of cases under a column titled case, number of deaths under a column titled deaths, and dates under a column titled date. The problem is that I don't know how to get the 1000th confirmed case numbers of countries and the number of cases thereafter.
Here is the question: "c)   The cumulative number of cases of 10 countries by days since 1000th confirmed case"

Here is my trying code:

```
library(utils)
COVID_data <-read.csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/csv", na.strings = "", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")


  above100th_cases <- ten_countries_cases %>% 
  filter(Cumulative_cases_Austria >= 1000|
           Cumulative_cases_Croatia >= 1000|
           Cumulative_cases_Denmark >= 1000|
           Cumulative_cases_Finland >= 1000|
           Cumulative_cases_France >= 1000|
           Cumulative_cases_Germany >= 1000|
           Cumulative_cases_Greece >= 1000|
           Cumulative_cases_Iceland >= 1000|
           Cumulative_cases_Italy >= 1000|
           Cumulative_cases_Spain >= 1000)
  
#Reshape the data set in order to draw line graphs 
above100th_case.m <- melt(above100th_cases,id.vars = 1)

# 0 values were below 100th, then skip these values to reach better graphs
above100th.m <- above100th_case.m %>% filter(value>0)
  
#Draw the graph by using ggplot
ggplot(above100th.m, aes(x=dateRep, y= value, color=variable))+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  #Arrange y axis, by considering min&max cumulative number of cases
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(from =5000, to =9000000, by=1001000)))+
  labs(x="Date",
       y="Cumulative Case Number",
       title="The Cumulative Number of Cases By Date") +
  facet_wrap(~variable)+
  theme_bw()
```

It is obviously wrong. I also tried to use filter(if() else) or when_case(), but I could not apply them.
I hope, I could explain myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this required?

```r
library(utils)
COVID_data <-read.csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/csv", na.strings = "", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")


library(tidyverse)
COVID_data %>% mutate(dateRep = as.Date(dateRep, '%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
  group_by(countriesAndTerritories) %>%
  arrange(dateRep) %>%
  mutate(cum_cases = cumsum(cases)) %>%
  filter(cum_cases >= 1000) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = dateRep, y = cum_cases, color = countriesAndTerritories))
```

[image]

---

Or if 10 countries are to be filtered

```r
ten_countries <- c('Denmark', 'Croatia', 'Austria', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Iceland', 'Italy', 'Spain')

COVID_data %>% filter(countriesAndTerritories %in% ten_countries) %>%
  mutate(dateRep = as.Date(dateRep, '%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
  group_by(countriesAndTerritories) %>%
  arrange(dateRep) %>%
  mutate(cum_cases = cumsum(cases)) %>%
  filter(cum_cases >= 1000) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = dateRep, y = cum_cases, color = countriesAndTerritories))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I do not have outputs, but I got it. It looks awesome. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad that it helped.  But you should get outputs too.  What are the error(s) you getting?